# Adjust uniform grid to number of children

Tags: c#, wpf, uniformgrid

I want to make a uniformGrid in wpf.

When I have 1 child, I want it to fill the grid, 2 childs I want 2 columns and when I have 3 or 4 children I want to have 2 rows and 2 columns.

So I've made a converter that checks how many children there are in the grid and based on that decides the number of rows / columns:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows;
using System.Globalization;

namespace UserControlSolution.Converter
{
    [ValueConversion(typeof(int), typeof(int))]
    public class CountToDimensionConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            int itemsCount = (int)value;
            int dimensionLength = 1;
            if (itemsCount > 0)
            {   
                if (string.Equals((string)parameter, "Rows", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    switch(itemsCount)
                    {
                        case 1: 
                        case 2: dimensionLength = 1;
                            break;
                        case 3: 
                        case 4: dimensionLength = 2;
                            break;
                    }
                }

                if (string.Equals((string)parameter, "Columns", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    switch(itemsCount)
                    {
                        case 1: dimensionLength = 1;
                            break;
                        case 2: 
                        case 3: 
                        case 4: dimensionLength = 2;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return dimensionLength;
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my xaml:

```
<customGridView:MyUniformGrid x:Name="AlarmButtonGrid" Margin="0,10" Grid.Row="2" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=AlarmPictureBox}"
        Rows="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Children.Count, Converter={StaticResource CountToDimensionConverter}, ConverterParameter=Rows}" 
        Columns="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Children.Count, Converter={StaticResource CountToDimensionConverter}, ConverterParameter=Columns}"> 

       <Button x:Name="Button1" Content="Sluit" Height="35" Style="{StaticResource CustomButtonStyle}" Margin="5" />
       <Button x:Name="Button2" Content="Verbergen" Height="35" Style="{StaticResource CustomButtonStyle}" Margin="5"/>
       <Button x:Name="Button3" Visibility="Collapsed" Content="Extra rij" Height="35" Style="{StaticResource CustomButtonStyle}" Margin="5"/>
       <Button x:Name="Button4" Visibility="Collapsed" Content="Extra rij" Height="35" Style="{StaticResource CustomButtonStyle}" Margin="5"/>
</customGridView:MyUniformGrid>
```

[Binding to Children.Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520060/binding-to-children-count)

I found in this post that I had to make a custom UniformGrid so that the Children.count of the grid actually works, so I did that.

This code all works, but I have one problem left.

These buttons can be dynamically made visibile or collapsed, and when a button is collapsed I don't want them to matter for the number of rows.
When button 3 & 4 are collapsed I don't want to have a 2nd row.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `MyUniformGrid` class, just add a new property:

```
public int VisibleCount
{
    get { return Children.OfType<UIElement>().Count(c => c.Visibility == 
              Visibility.Visible); }
}
```

... and bind to that instead:

```
<customGridView:MyUniformGrid x:Name="AlarmButtonGrid" Margin="0,10" Grid.Row="2" 
    Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=AlarmPictureBox}" Rows="{Binding 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=VisibleCount, Converter={
    StaticResource CountToDimensionConverter}, ConverterParameter=Rows}" Columns="{
    Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=VisibleCount, Converter={
    StaticResource CountToDimensionConverter}, ConverterParameter=Columns}">                    
    <Button x:Name="Button1" Content="Sluit" Height="35" Style="{StaticResource CustomButtonStyle}" Margin="5" />
    <Button x:Name="Button2" Content="Verbergen" Height="35" Style="{StaticResource CustomButtonStyle}" Margin="5"/>
    <Button x:Name="Button3" Visibility="Collapsed" Content="Extra rij" Height="35" Style="{StaticResource CustomButtonStyle}" Margin="5"/>
    <Button x:Name="Button4" Visibility="Collapsed" Content="Extra rij" Height="35" Style="{StaticResource CustomButtonStyle}" Margin="5"/>
</customGridView:MyUniformGrid>
```

The only point to note is that you may need to call the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event whenever you add or remove items from the `Grid.Children` collection... alternatively, you could implement this as a `DependencyProperty` instead.

Comment: The visibleCount always returns 0, even when I replace your linq with just Children.Count(). Any idea why this is ?

Comment: I already have that PropertyChanged event in my ObservableUIElementCollection add/remove methods. Here you can find my ObseravbleUIElementCollection class : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520060/binding-to-children-count

Comment: `Children.Count()` is still `LinQ`... `Children.Count` is not. Either way, I think it is because the item collection does not implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. I know you said you implemented that, but I always add a 'manual' call to `NotifyPropertyChanged("VisibleCount"); just after any code that adds or deletes items from the collection... it works ok for me.

Comment: this is better: Children.OfType<UIElement>().Count(c => c.Visibility == 
Visibility.Visible);

Comment: Sure, if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it will be to add/remove the listener to IsVisibleChanged on the UIElement in Add/Remove methods of your uniformgrid.

And put the logic in the handler to calculate the rows/columns depeneding on the Visible children. then you will not required the self binding for Rows/columns and converter.

ie. in Add method

```
   element.IsVisibleChanged += new DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(Child_IsVisibleChanged);
```

and then in handler

```
    private void Child_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int visibleChildrenCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.Children.Count; i++)
        {
            if (grid.Children[i].Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
            {
                visibleChildrenCount++;
            }
        }

        //Here you can set your Rows and Columns depending on visiblechildrenCount
    }
```

you can rather create the seperate method to do this and call that method from Add element and remove element method also.
dont forget to remove the handler while removing the element in Remove method