# TabItem UIElement OnPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `TabControl` with a `SelectionChanged` event. When the selected `TabPage` changes, I want to get notified for the selected `TabPage` if a value of one of the `UIElements` on the `TabPage` has changed.

```
private FrameworkElement CurrentFrameworkElement { get; set; }

public TabEvents(DispatcherEvents dispatcherEvents)
    : base(dispatcherEvents)
{
    EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(System.Windows.Controls.TabControl), System.Windows.Controls.TabControl.SelectionChangedEvent, new SelectionChangedEventHandler(TabControl_SelectionChanged), true);
}

private void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Source is System.Windows.Controls.TabControl)
    {
        var ti = ((System.Windows.Controls.TabControl)e.Source).SelectedItem as TabItem;
        CurrentFrameworkElement = e.Source as System.Windows.Controls.TabControl;
    }
}
```

With this code I can get the current `TabItem`. How can I detect changes of UIElement values inside the current `TabItem`? For example entering text in a `TextBox` or toggling a `CheckBox` should give a notification.

I found an implementation of ObservableUIElementCollection [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520060/binding-to-children-count) but I don't know if I can use it for this scenario and how.

Comment: To get the changes in your textboxes, checkboxes and so on you have to bind the text property or the ischecked property to a property in your window you can find many tutorials online on how to use WPF explaining how to do it

Comment: @GlenThomas yes, I have access to the View / ViewModel

Comment: Take a look at the basic WPF concepts like databinding in combination with MVVM pattern and how they are used. Perhaps something like [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robertgreen/2013/11/14/getting-started-with-mvvm/) makes it easier to start.

Comment: MVVM? Listen to `INotifyPropertyChanged` event of corresponding `TabItem` ViewModel. Btw, notification is basically ViewModels communications, there is absolutely no need to have logic in the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can track your changes within the ViewModel. I have done something similar by marking a field from the property setters:

```
bool _hasChanged = false;

public string Name
{
    get
    {
        return _name;
    }

    set
    {
        if (value != _name)
        {
            _name = value;
            _hasChanged = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Then when your tab changes check the value of the _hasChanged field